# Spring boot kafka consumer, one of two listeners not triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two spring boot projects A and B. I have downloaded the apache kafka and started both zooleeper and kafka.

In both A and B I have only one consumer group. In the consumer class :

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "test")
public void consume(String message) {
    logger.info(String.format("Message received -> %s", message));
}
```

This is the code I have in the consumer class for both projects A and B.

When I try to publish a message with topic "test". The message is getting consumed in project A. I'm able to get the output in logger "Message Received". Whereas in project B, I'm not able to get the output in the logger. But when I try to monitor the consumed messages with terminal, the message is consumed. The problem is that the consume function in project B is not Working.

Could anyone please help on this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the consume function in project B is not working ? Could it be the case that the logging is not working or the log file is not the one you are inspecting ?

Comment: No, it is not working. If any other functionality is implemented in consumer function, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you stop project A, just run project B and see the result if it can consume message.
Second, check the bean you config for Kafka consummer on project B and set another name for `Bean listener` example:

```java
    @Bean("anotherName")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory...{}
```

let's try